# Selenium RC against a Cassini webserver

Tags: selenium, cassini

I'm trying to run Selenium RC against my ASP.NET code running on a Cassini webserver.

The web application works when i browse it directly but when running through Selenium I get

HTTP ERROR: 403
Forbidden for Proxy

---

Running Selenium i interactive mode I start a new session with:

```
cmd=getNewBrowserSession&1=*iexplore&2=http://localhost:81/  
cmd=open&1=http://localhost:81/default.aspx&sessionId=199578
```

I get the above error in the Selenium browser, the command window tells me OK.

---

Any input?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that both Selenium and the webserver is running on localhost.
It works if I run with the "iehta" instead of "iexplore".

Answer (score 1):

Your Selenium server and web server should run of different ports.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is part of the issue but, cassini can not be accessed from another machine.  It is meant for local development only.  I ran into this problem today and am trying UltiDev (cassini wrapper) to get around it: http://www.ultidev.com/products/Cassini/index.htm

Comment: not sure I would use that software, but I thought this was a valid point.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried running RC with the -proxyInjection flag?